# mysql error #1064

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

i keep getting this error code #1064 when trying to  create my products table  this is the   code im tryng to use

```
  CREATE TABLE products
(
prod_id int NOT NULL,
prod_name character(20) NOT NULL,
Price decimal(19, 4),
on_hand int,
supp_id int,
PRIMARY KEY (prod_id),
FOREIGN KEY (supp_id)
);
```

if anyone could tell me  what am doing wrong and/or  give me solution that will work that would be greatly appreciated

thanks

Comment: The error is probably telling you exactly, what's wrong. From a first glance, at least the `FOREIGN KEY` statement is wrong. (hint: what should it reference?)

Comment: You posted same question in another thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add which table the foreign key references.  Below would be if the table containing supp_Id was called suppTable and had referencing key supp_id.

**Edit:** updated to reflect your referencing table being suppliers with supp_id referencing column.  Note that supp_id on suppliers must be an int for this to work and should be the PRIMARY KEY of the referencing table (or have an index created for the column).

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    prod_id int NOT NULL,
    prod_name character(20) NOT NULL,
    Price decimal(19, 4),
    on_hand int,
    supp_id int,
    PRIMARY KEY (prod_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (supp_id) REFERENCES suppliers(supp_id)
);
```

Comment: i have got a suppliers table with a column   called  supp_id

Comment: ugh this is so frustrating  i a now getting this error #1005 - Can't create table 'computer_wholesale.products' (errno: 150) (Details…)

Comment: Did you define supp_id as the PRIMARY KEY on suppliers?  If you didn't, you'll need to add that so that MySQL adds the clustered index for you.  Otherwise, you can run this to create one: CREATE INDEX idx_suppliers_suppid ON suppliers (supp_id );  However I strongly recommend making it your PRIMARY KEY on suppliers.

Comment: got it!  just relised the supp_id wasnt an int   but  thank you very much for your help.